# Xcode 6 crash when hitting run, persistent error in code

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 6 won't build when I run simulator on mac or on my own ipad...

The last run in failed to build because of an error, which I fixed.  Yet the error message, telling me that addObject is not a member, which clearly nonsensical, still remains in the code.  I rewrote the code around the error and nothing is making it disappear, not restarting Xcode or my computer has helped either.  I assume this has something to do with the crash.

Any idea what I can do?

[image]

Comment: This could be related to a bracket mismatch. Try re-indenting and seeing if you can see a mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error in the code, hit `command`+`shift`+`k` to clean your project. This might fix your problem.

If it still occurs, even after rebooting and restarting Xcode I'd recommend to reinstall Xcode completely: deinstall it first (using CleanMyMac for instance) and then download and install it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it did eventually clear and the crashing stopped, but a 'clean up your project' command is great to know of, I was hoping that existed.